# Simplify the equation, containing radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble simplifying this equation, while keeping it as an exact expression.

$x=\sqrt{28800-14400\sqrt{3}}$

I'm looking for the steps to change that above equation into $120\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: There is the obvious factoring as $12\sqrt{200-10\sqrt{3}}$. But I doubt that's what you wanted.

Comment: Why are you needing to simplify it?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is great for problems like this. It'll usually give you a step-by-step solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=\sqrt{28800-14400\sqrt{3}}\\\implies x=\sqrt{14400(2-\sqrt{3})}\\\implies \color{blue}{{x=120\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}}$.

Comment: But don't forget $2-\sqrt3=\frac{4-2\sqrt3}{2}=\frac{(\sqrt3-1)^2}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

$x=\sqrt{28800-14400\sqrt{3})}=\sqrt{14400(2-\sqrt{3})}=\sqrt{144(100)(2-\sqrt{3})}=12(10)\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}=120\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: It should be $28800$ instead of $2880$.

Comment: You can denest the last radical

Answer (score 1):

$28800-1440\sqrt{3}=144(200+10\sqrt{3})$

Comment: There's a typo ...